# How to close a subview (UIView)

Tags: xamarin.ios

I use a subview (UIView) with labels, text and buttons to connect to a server. Works OK. When finised and successful i need to close the subview to revert to its parent view. This happens in a delegate of the OK button of a UIAlertView, within the subview. (equivalent of Me.Close in VB.net)
Any suggestion? Could not find any docu so far.

Answer (score 2):

Use `UIView.RemoveFromSuperview()` to remove it, see [Apple doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html).  I would also call `Dispose()` on the view.

Another alternative is to use a `UIViewController` and `PresentModalViewController()`, this is generally how you show a popup view over another.

Comment: Add like to note that PresentModalViewControllerAnimated() is obsolete and PresentViewController() should be used instead.

Comment: I did not have MonoDevelop in front of me, changed it.